# iOS 7.1 Crash: -[UINavigationBar setItems:animated:]

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7.1

I'm experiencing a crash that is brand new across all iPhone devices with iOS 7.1 and I'm wondering if others have seen the same.

```
Date/Time:           2014-03-11 11:46:00.795 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  6

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x2d4dbefe __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x37c70ce2 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreFoundation                       0x2d4dbe40 +[NSException raise:format:] + 106
3   UIKit                                0x2fe319a0 -[UINavigationBar setItems:animated:] + 98
4   Document                             0x97aa6 -[FHHorizontalSplitViewController setVisibility:animated:] (FHHorizontalSplitViewController.m:233)
5   Document                             0x98882 __44-[FHHorizontalSplitViewReplaceSegue perform]_block_invoke (FHHorizontalSplitViewController.m:450)
6   Document                             0x9814a __72-[FHHorizontalSplitViewController _changeViewFramesAnimated:completion:]_block_invoke (FHHorizontalSplitViewController.m:335)
7   UIKit                                0x2fd43788 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 278
8   UIKit                                0x2fd433d2 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 172
9   UIKit                                0x2fd432ea -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 60
10  QuartzCore                           0x2f98de06 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 228
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x38159d3a _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3815c6be _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 272
13  CoreFoundation                       0x2d4a6674 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 2
14  CoreFoundation                       0x2d4a4f40 __CFRunLoopRun + 1302
15  CoreFoundation                       0x2d40f7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
16  CoreFoundation                       0x2d40f586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
17  GraphicsServices                     0x3237c6ce GSEventRunModal + 132
18  UIKit                                0x2fd6e88c UIApplicationMain + 1130
19  Document                             0x80dbe main (main.m:12)
```

The code in question (`FHHorizontalSplitViewController`) is a custom `UIViewController` container that is installed in a `UINavigationController`. The gist is it's splits the top and bottom halves of the iPhone screen and selections in the top half expands or contracts the bottom half. When a child-view controller has been expanded to fill the screen, the container asks it for its `UINavigationItem` and sets the navigation bar item.

The interesting thing is this crash is new on iOS 7.1; it works fine on 6.x and 7.0.x.

**Have others seen new crashes in this method call that didn't happen before?**

The crashing call site:

```
UINavigationController *navVC = self.navigationController;
if (navVC) {
    NSMutableArray *navigationItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:navVC.navigationBar.items;
    NSInteger lastItem = [navigationItems count] - 1;
    navigationItems[lastItem] = [self navigationItem];
    [navVC.navigationBar setItems:navigationItems animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `-[UINavigationBar setItem:animated:]` on a navigation bar that is being managed by a `UINavigationController` is disallowed (and newly enforced) in iOS 7.1